# Let int8_t num = -1. Why does printf("%u", num) overflow to T_MAX32 instead of T_MAX8?

Tags: c

`int8_t` is an 8-bit signed integer. Therefore, its value is anywhere in the range [-128...127].

```
int8_t num = -1;
printf("%u",num);
```

Output:

> 4294967295

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Your program behaviour is not defined.

%u cannot be used as a format specifier for int8_t since it's a signed type and %u is for unsigned types.

Use %d instead, and rely on the C standard guaranteed automatic promotion of num to an int type.

Comment: To be more specific, the `printf` format specifiers **do not convert argument types**. They require an argument whose type matches the specifier, and convert it to a character string presentation for output.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using the incorrect format specifier for `printf` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The behavior you experienced cannot be depended on to be consistent between different compilers or even different builds of the same compiler.

That being said, here's is what most likely happened.

Any argument to `printf` after the first is of an unspecified type.  So when `num` is passed to it, it can't do an exact type check.  What ends up happening is that the value of `num` is promoted to type `int`.

From section 6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **2** The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> —  An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type
>   (other  than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is
>   less  than  or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int`.
>
> —  A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> **If  an `int`
>   can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as  restricted 
>   by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is  converted  to  an
>   `int`;** otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an `unsigned int`. These  are 
>   called  the *integer promotions*.  All  other  types  are  unchanged  by
>   the integer promotions.

Because `num` was being used in a context where an `int` could be used, its value in the function call was promoted to `int`.

Assuming a 32-bit `int` and 2's compliment representation of negative numbers, the orginal binary representation `11111111` is converted to `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`.  If printed with the `%u` format specifier, it assumes this representation is unsigned so it prints `4294967295`.

Had you used the `%d` format specifier, which expects a signed value, it would have printed `-1`.

To reiterate however, what you are seeing is undefined behavior.  Other machines / compilers / optimization settings might yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

To print an `int8_t`, the C standard provids the format specifier macro `PRIi8` from `<inttypes.h>`.

```
printf("%" PRIi8, num);
```

Although, `%d` is fine to use to print an `int8_t` due to C's *default argument promotions*, you can simply use it for *all* signed types. You can see the format specifiers for other fixed width types in [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) as well.